# Is it possible to install Piwik and send it fake data to test its features?

Tags: php, analytics, testing, matomo

I found Piwik as a good open source solution for website analytics.

Is it possible to run Piwik and see its features using fake data rather than a live site?

Not only the demo version which is available in the Piwik site. For example create a website locally to my PC using Joomla, install Piwik and create fake data in order to check its features.

Comment: Sure. Why not? For what it is worth Piwik seems to be about the best there is free or not. There is one other competitor that is very good too, but I forget who that is simply because the truth be told, Piwik is far simpler to use and intuitive. I use sawmill which is expensive, and I still may/will switch to Piwik.

Comment: @closetnoc thank you for your answer. But how can I create fake data based on the categories of piwik demo http://demo.piwik.org/index.php?module=CoreHome&action=index&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday#/module=Dashboard&action=embeddedIndex&idSite=7&period=day&date=yesterday&idDashboard=1 ?

Comment: You will have to read the documentation, but I think it can also access log files, so you can take your site log files and copy them locally and see what you get.

Answer (score 3):

Piwik has a plugin called the 'Visitor Generator' which can generate fake data for testing purposes. It is available [here, on the Piwik Plugins Marketplace](http://plugins.piwik.org/VisitorGenerator). You can use it to generate 100% fake data or a mix of fake and real data from your own logs. A blog post giving a features overview with sample commands is [here, on the Piwik blog](http://piwik.org/blog/2014/10/generating-test-data/).

If you want to just start using it right away without reading the linked documentation, click on 'Administration' in the top menu and then click 'Marketplace' in the left menu as shown here where you will see the Visitor Generator plugin. Next click on 'Install' (top right of the plugin detail) to install it.

[image: Piwik plugin marketplace with Visitor Generator plugin highlighted]

Comment: Can you clarify which plugin this is, or point the user how to use it?